# Datetime format in python is not as same as format

Tags: python, json, datetime, date-format

I have a date in my dataframe with format like this

```
"2018-05-01"
"2018-05-02"
"2018-05-03"
```

I want to convert the date into something like this in my JSON

```
"2018-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"
"2018-05-02T00:00:00.000Z"
```

I had tried using  `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`
but the result is become something like `1523404800000` in my JSON file. What should I do to get a format like `"2018-05-02T00:00:00.000Z"` in my JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `date_format='iso'` in [`df.to_json()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

csvdata = '''\
date
2018-05-01
2018-05-02
2018-05-03'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(csvdata)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+')

# without conversion
print(df.to_json()) 

# with conversion
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print(df.to_json()) 

# with conversion and adding date_format = iso
print(df.to_json(date_format='iso'))
```

Prints:

```
{"date":{"0":"2018-05-01","1":"2018-05-02","2":"2018-05-03"}}
{"date":{"0":1525132800000,"1":1525219200000,"2":1525305600000}}
{"date":{"0":"2018-05-01T00:00:00.000Z","1":"2018-05-02T00:00:00.000Z","2":"2018-05-03T00:00:00.000Z"}}
```

Comment: thanks Anton. Works flawlessly. can i convert null values to \u0000 too ?

Comment: @Ducker Now that is a harder question. Possibly use some string replace?